# How to retrieve data json after Ajax post form to database

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have some code insert data to database, i want after ajax save data to database, client side automatically retrieve callback json, this json will use as verification when data saved or not. data has save, but json not show in console. Any one can help me?

this my client code :

```
<script>
$("#savependuduk").click(function () {
    var formdata = $('.form-input-penduduk').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '?page=action',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formdata,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.info);
            demo.showNotification('top', 'left', 'Berhasil Input', '2');
            $('input[type="text"],textarea,select,radio').val('');

        }
    });

});
```

and this server code :

```
$qu = mysql_query("insert into mst_penduduk (nik,no_kk,nama,tempat_lahir,tgl_lahir,jen_kel,alamat,rt,rw,kelurahan,kecamatan,kabupaten,provinsi,negara,agama,status_perkawinan,pendidikan,pekerjaan,status_keluarga,status_kependudukan,kewarganegaraan) "
        . "values ('$nik','$no_kk','$nama','$tempat_lahir','$tanggal_lahir','$jenis_kelamin','$alamat','$rt','$rw','$kelurahan','$kecamatan','$kabupaten','$provinsi','$negara','$agama','$status_perkawinan','$pendidikan','$pekerjaan','$status_keluarga','$status_kependudukan','$status_kewarganegaraan')");

if ($qu) {
    $stat = "success";
} else {
    $stat = "failed";
}
$status = $stat;
echo json_encode(array('info' => $status));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the returned data need to be parsed?

```
success: function (data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(json.info);
    ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

I not use json, but this Solved my case :

Client :

```
$("#savependuduk").click(function () {
    var formdata = $('.form-input-penduduk').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "masuk") {
                demo.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Berhasil menyimpan', '2', 'done');
                $('input[type="text"],textarea,select,radio').val('');
            } else if (data == "ada") {
                demo.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Gagal menyimpan, nik ini telah terdaftar sebelumnya', '4', 'clear');
            }
            else {
                demo.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Gagal menyimpan, pastikan kolom isian lengkap', '4', 'clear');
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            demo.showNotification('top', 'right', 'Gagal menyimpan, cek koneksi anda', '4', 'clear');
        }
    });

});
```

Server :

```
 $qu = mysql_query("insert into mst_penduduk (nik,no_kk,nama,tempat_lahir,tgl_lahir,jen_kel,alamat,rt,rw,kelurahan,kecamatan,kabupaten,provinsi,negara,agama,status_perkawinan,pendidikan,pekerjaan,status_keluarga,status_kependudukan,kewarganegaraan) "
            . "values ('$nik','$no_kk','$nama','$tempat_lahir','$tanggal_lahir','$jenis_kelamin','$alamat','$rt','$rw','$kelurahan','$kecamatan','$kabupaten','$provinsi','$negara','$agama','$status_perkawinan','$pendidikan','$pekerjaan','$status_keluarga','$status_kependudukan','$status_kewarganegaraan')");

    if ($qu) {
        echo "masuk";
    } else {
        echo "gagal";
    }
```